# How Do I Combine Two Numbers in a Variable Without Adding Them? - Python

Tags: python

I have a basic Python encryption program. The program is pretty much done, but I keep getting errors because of the way Python is building my variable.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
A = 4
B = 2
C = 3

for i in range (3):
     A=A, ((B*2) + C)

A = (((4, 7), 7), 7)
```

I want A to output 4, 7, 7, 7 and as it loops, it adds numbers onto the end instead of adding them together. The issue here is that for whatever reason, I can't target specific values, for example, if I did

```
print (A[2])
```

The output would be an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/Desktop/Python/Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print (A[2])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Ignoring the above code, what is the best way I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to sum the numbers or concatenate them?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to concatenate them.

Comment: I want A to output 4, 7, 7, 7

Comment: So in essence, you want `A` to be a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and append to it in each loop?

Comment: The output is A = (((4, 7), 7), 7) and that wouldn't be an issue, but I cannot target a specific value by typing A[2] because it errors as seen above.

Comment: Yep, I feel really quite stupid right now. Thanks Dhke, didn't think about that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this,

```
A = 4
B = 2
C = 3

l = [A]
for i in range (3):
    l.extend([B*2 + C])

print(l)
# [4, 7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you, some how I forgot I could use and append a list. Will mark is as answered when I can. :)

Comment: @Spookichicken, you can do that any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using a tuple you can do it like this:

```
A = 4
B = 2
C = 3

A = (A,) # Convert A to tuple
for i in range(3):
     A += ((B*2) + C,)

print(A)
# (4, 7, 7, 7)
```

Note: tuples are immutable, which means you are creating a new tuple in each iteration, this can be an expensive operation if the loop is very big.